# StackOverflow Careers messages don't exists

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Lately I receive messages to my StackOverflow Careers linked email. At the bottom part of it, you see the **reply to this message** and another link to the message, but when I click on it I'm redirected to the page not found page. [image]

Additionally, I enter into my StackOverflow Careers profile and there are no messages, applications or any other things at all.

Is everything disappearing?

Comment: It all moved to http://stackoverflow.com/jobs, so old links might be broken.

Comment: @Patrick no, it's still there - at least for me.

Comment: Hi guys, in my case in none of both profiles :(

Comment: Agree it looks like a bug, hopefully a dev will come over and have a look.

Comment: Yes, it seems that due to the moving to stackoverflow.com/jobs, data is being loosed. Let's see if dev comes upon a solution for this.

Comment: @AlexJ Would you do us a favor and forward the message you received to careers@stackoverflow.com with a note referencing this question? That'll help us troubleshoot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For posterity's sake: this has been resolved working directly with @AlexJ.

In this particular case the root cause was that there were two accounts: one that the message was sent to, and the other that the poster was logged in to. This in turn generated the page not found.

For those experiencing this in the future (for any link emailed to them by us for that matter) this is usually the cause, and emailing us at careers at stackoverflow dot com will allow us to identify this and merge the accounts for you.